# Xcode: How to create a dSym and still strip symbols?

Tags: xcode, macos, crash-reports, dsym

I'd like to create a dSym file when building my Release build but I'd also like to strip symbols in the executable to keep things away from nosy eyes. Is it possible to do both? Or are they mutually exclusive?

I'm using this:

```
GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES,
GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = full, 
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym, 
COPY_PHASE_STRIP=YES, 
DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME).dSYM", 
DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH = "$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/dSyms"
```

...which DOES create the dSym file but unfortunately keeps the symbols in my executable.

???

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across this and saw it was open.
As I see the username is similar I presume it might be related to this:
https://forum.juce.com/t/generating-osx-dsyms-and-still-stripping-symbols/23731

I've made a [JUCE](https://www.juce.com) project that provides an example how to strip symbols while maintaining dSYM for later use.

https://github.com/talaviram/SymbolFriendlyPlugIn

TL;DR -
This make xcodebuild keep the symbols -

`xcodebuild -project "./Builds/MacOSX/SymbolFriendlyPlugin.xcodeproj" -configuration "Release" GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym`

The xcode project itself should be pretty similar to what you've showed above:
[image]

I was able to get symbols properly only with `xcodebuild` which is ok as for release I guess you'd like some scripting to keep things as automated as possible.